# Find Euler trail given a function that finds Euler Circuit.

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Assume you have a computer program called `print-EulerCircuit(G)` that returns a euler circuit given a graph as an input.

A Euler trail is a walk that hits every edge once in a graph and is not closed.

In pseudocode write a function `print-EulerTrail(G)` that takes in a graph G and returns a Euler trail.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri does this mean it's not possible

Comment: Hold on. The question doesn't say that the trail and the circuit are in the same graph. We just have to use the circuit code to generate the trail code.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connected (isolated vertices are allowed) graph $G$ will have an Euler trail iff it has exactly $2$ vertices with odd degree. In that case, adding an edge between the two odd vertices will make their degrees even, so that now all the vertices have even degrees and the modified graph $G'$ has an Euler circuit.

Assuming $G$ has an Euler trail, locate the $2$ odd vertices and add an edge between them to yield $G'$. Use `getEulerCircuit(G)` to find an Euler circuit $C$ in $G'$. Now remove the added edge from $C$, yielding the required Euler trail.